# jquery flexigrid selectors

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I'm trying to understand the flexigrid at [FlexiGrid](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/source/browse/trunk/flexigrid.js?r=4)

At line # 1161 & 1163 I dint understand the jQuery selectors:  $('div',g.pDiv).html(html); & $('.pReload',g.pDiv).click(function(){g.populate()}); But these doesn't look like the multiple selectors, Please suggest me to understand this code.

```
                $('div',g.pDiv).html(html);

            $('.pReload',g.pDiv).click(function(){g.populate()});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is the context to look inside of for that selector, so this:

```
$('div',g.pDiv).html(html);
```

Is *really*:

```
$(g.pDiv).find('div').html(html);
```

...so it's looking for `<div>` elements inside that stored `g.Div` element the plugin saves a reference to.

Comment: Thanks :) now I got it, if there are quotes in between the selectors then it is a multiple selector or else it is selector & context.

Comment: @user237865 - yup, exactly :)